# Nginx Setup on Ubuntu

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ubuntu, nginx, natty

I'm trying to setup nginx with passenger to work on Ubuntu with RVM.
I should get my apps home page when i go to localhost, instead I recieve the default nginx home page.

```
user  antarr;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    passenger_root /home/antarr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@myapplication/gems/passenger-3.0.7;
    passenger_ruby /home/antarr/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.2-p180@myapplication/ruby;

    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

        # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
        #}

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    root           html;
        #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
        #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
        #    include        fastcgi_params;
        #}

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #    deny  all;
        #}
    }


    # HTTP SERVER
    server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    root /rails_apps/Blog/public;   # <--- be sure to point to 'public'!
    passenger_enabled on;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you've defined two servers which are listening on port 80. Remove the first one and it should work.

Comment: I removed the Server{....} part now I get restart :instance unknown when trying to restart nginx

Comment: Thanks I got it, changed the port on the first and had to restart machine